# Batch script pipe and redirect to file

Tags: python, batch-file

There is something with batch scripting and pipes that I"m missing.

I want to check that python has the necessary libraries installed and then error out if it does not.

using this command to check

`python -m pip freeze -r ./requirements.txt | findstr "WARNING"`

by itself it outputs exactly what I need. however, I try to redirect output to a file or a variable like

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('python -m pip freeze -r ./requirements.txt | findstr "WARNING"') do set output=%%i
```

or a file

`python -m pip freeze -r ./requirements.txt | findstr "WARNING" > tmpfile.txt`

and both are empty. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of FOR /F, you need to escape the pipe character

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('python -m pip freeze -r ./requirements.txt ^| findstr "WARNING"') do (
  set output=%%i
)
```

Comment: That works better... but it's just giving me the last line of the python output, not the output from the findstr on it

Comment: @mrodus, `(echo %%i)>>tmpfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here as I understand is that the WARNING command is outputted to the Standard error handle rather than the stdout so the output isn't captured by the for.

redirecting it to standard out and adding the escape to the | seem to take care of the problem.

`for /f "delims=" %%i in ('2^>^&1 python -m pip freeze -r ./requirements.txt ^| findstr WARNING') do set output=%%i`